# how to webscrape a dynamic website without the ID of the buttom by python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to websrcape some information the following website:

https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data1=[]
data2=[]

async def get_data():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1", waitUntil="networkidle0")

    html = await page.content()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    titles = soup.find_all('a')
    for title in titles[7:]:
        data1.append(title.text)
    infs = soup.find_all("span",{"class" :"ng-star-inserted"})
    for inf in infs:
        data2.append(inf.text.strip())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_data())

data1_e = data1[0:-5][::2]
data1_o = data1[1:-5][::2]
data2_e = data2[0:-5][::2]
data2_o = data2[1:-5][::2]
    

d1 = pd.DataFrame(data1_o)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2_e)
d3 = pd.DataFrame(data2_o)

result = pd.concat([d1,d2,d3], axis=1,join='inner')
print(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(result).to_excel('HIHI.xlsx', index = False)
```

However, this website is an dynamic website which most of its content are hidden by the "show more" buttom on the bottom of the page.

Therefore, I was trying to use Selenium to click the buttom.

```
import selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1")
more_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "showMore")
more_button.click()
```

However, the buttom doesn't have any ID of it and I don't know what should i do for the next step?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the button has not load yet, you can use `WebDriverWait()` to select the button when it was loaded.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1")

w = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
more_button = w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.showMore')))
more_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you, but how does it link back to my scraping code?

Comment: What does "link back to scraping code" mean?

Comment: You can scrap data by selenium, or download entire page as text file by selenium, then use bs4 to scrap the downloaded file.